# Finding patterns in expressions

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a huge expression (spanning 70 pages) involving  polynomials and logarithms and polylogarithms. A sample of that looks as below:

```
(x*(2 + x + 4*x^2 + x^3 + 2*x^4 + 4*z - x*z + 8*x^2*z - x^3*z + 
    4*x^4*z -10*x*z^2 - 2*x^2*z^2 - 10*x^3*z^2 + 6*x^2*z^3)) +  
  6*Log[z]*Log[-x + z] + (12*I)*Log[Z] + 6*Log[Z]^2 + 
  12*PolyLog[2, Y^(-1)] + 6*PolyLog[2,x/((1 + x^2)/x - z)] - 
  6*PolyLog[2, x*((1 + x^2)/x - z)] + 6*PolyLog[2, x/z] - 
  6*PolyLog[2, x*z] + 12*PolyLog[2, Z^(-1)]))/(3*(1 + x)^6))
```

I have many such kind of patterns involving `Polylog`; I want to make a list of all such unique patterns that are appearing in the huge expression. I have tried `Cases` but it is not working. Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you've tried? `Cases[*yourstuff*, PolyLog[x_, y_] :> {x, y}, ∞]` returns something useful, but I'm not sure it's what you're after.

Comment: Cases['expression',PolyLog[a_,b_]]  is what i had tried

Comment: Two points. 1) the expression you post above has two unmatched right parentheses  at end -- `... + 12*PolyLog[2, Z^(-1)]))/(3*(1 + x)^6)`. 2) in Mathematica pattern matching works the same for expressions with any head. That means the head `List` is not treated specially.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I had missed two  right parentheses, i had copied it directly from the file...

Answer (score 4):

`Cases` is the right choice.

```
expr = ((((x*(2 + x + 4*x^2 + x^3 + 2*x^4 + 4*z - x*z + 8*x^2*z - x^3*z + 
         4*x^4*z - 10*x*z^2 - 2*x^2*z^2 - 10*x^3*z^2 + 6*x^2*z^3)) + 
     6*Log[z]*Log[-x + z] + (12*I)*Log[Z] + 6*Log[Z]^2 + 
     12*PolyLog[2, Y^(-1)] + 6*PolyLog[2, x/((1 + x^2)/x - z)] - 
     6*PolyLog[2, x*((1 + x^2)/x - z)] + 6*PolyLog[2, x/z] - 
     6*PolyLog[2, x*z] + 12*PolyLog[2, Z^(-1)]))/(3*(1 + x)^6));

Cases[expr, HoldPattern[PolyLog[__]], Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It is working fine.